# Querying entities which have a specific collection entry using HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, collections, hql

I have `Item` objects which have a **collection of attributes** defined as a **map**. Now I want to retrieve all objects which have a specific attribute (by `name`, `locale` and `value`)

An expecert of the `Item` mapping:

```
<map table="ITEM_ATTRIBUTES" name="attributes">
  <key column="item_id" foreign-key="fk_itmr_attrbts_itmrs"/>
  <composite-index class="LocalizedKey">
    <key-property name="name" column="name"/>
    <key-property name="locale" column="locale" length="32"/>
  </composite-index>
  <element column="value" type="escapedString" not-null="true"/>
</map>
```

This HQL (with `:key` as `LocalizedKey` and `:value` as `String`)

```
from Item item
where item.attributes[:key] = :value
```

doesn't work and produces the following output

```
error: composite-index appears in []
```

I created a workaround by using plain SQL in my query. But i'd like to know **if there is a way to do this in HQL**.

my plain-sql workaround:

```
select i.* from items i
left join item_attributes a on a.item_id = i.id
where a.name = :name
and a.locale = :locale
and a.value = :value
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation hints that the index() operator should return you the key from your map.  Given that your key is a composite object, I'm not totally certain what you're going to be able to do with that in your query.  I apologize for not being able to test this out before giving you the suggestion, but here's what I'd try just to see what you get:

```
from Item item join item.attributes attr where attr.index().name = :name 
       and attr.index().locale = :locale and attr.value = :value
```